# Present difference in estimates for positively-skewed continuous outcomes

Tags: modeling, data-transformation, poisson-distribution, skewness, log-linear

I'm working with a dataset containing results from two types of cognitive tests:

1. Pairs-matching test (say, $Y_1$), which recorded as number of incorrect matches (discrete count of mistakes, ranging from 0 - 12), and
2. Reaction time test ($Y_2$), which recorded as time in millisecond.

Both variables are **positively skewed**

I tried to compare results on these tests between different groups of categorical variables (e.g. Gender) and continuous variables (e.g. Age). Normally, I would run a multivariate linear regression model and present the coefficient as mean difference between groups (for categorical variables) or mean difference per 1 unit increase in continuous variables.

However, since the distribution is not normal, I think this approach could lead to biased estimates. Therefore, I came up with two alternatives which I could think of:

1. Log-transform the data with $ln(Y_1+1)$ and $ln(Y_2)$, run linear regression as usual, and present the coefficients as mean difference in log scale, or back transform and present the coefficients as (geometric) mean difference in linear scale (this approach has been done before in a published article using the same dataset)
2. Fit different regression models (e.g. Poisson regression with robust standard errors as suggested in this [blog](http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/)). This model came first to my mind as I think $Y_1$ is a count data, but I am not sure if this also applies to $Y_2$.

Regarding this, my questions are:

1. What is the best way to present such difference in estimates? In a sense that, for example, a reader can easily see that on average the cognitive test results are better in one group compared to the other and tell how big that difference is (or how they change for each one unit increase in continuous variables).
2. Are there better transformation or models to fit such data? I read about GLMM and negative-binomial regression but not sure if they are any better in this case.

Comment: $Y_1$ is a discrete count (zero counts are certainly possible) and so presumably only deserves the appellation "zero-inflated" when compared to some idea about the proportion of $0$s (such as some distributional model, perhaps).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I have edited the original post :)